# Adding water just after fermentation has started, wait, or not worth it?

Tags: fermentation, original-gravity

I brewed this recipe last night:
http://beerrecipes.org/showrecipe.php?recipeid=1254#sthash.U5JgSM6X.GnSCunwe.dpbs

I don't think we added enough water and it looks like the OG is around 1.1 although the reading could be bad. The beer is already high alcohol content at 8.7%.

1. Would it be more dangerous then it's worth to top up the fermenter that has just started to 5.5 gallons
2. Should I wait and add bottled water in the secondary fermentation?
3. Just forget about it and wait to see how it turns out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called [*high gravity brewing*](http://www.craftbeer.com/craft-beer-muses/high-gravity-beer-big-risk-bigger-reward). This technique is oft employed by macro brewers to produce more beer with less fermenter space. They dilute after fermentation is complete.

Some Useful Resources:

- [Brew Your Own Article](http://byo.com/hops/item/237-blending-for-volume-techniques)
- [Beer and Wine Journal Article Part 1](http://beerandwinejournal.com/expand-theory/)
- [Beer and Wine Journal Article Part 2](http://beerandwinejournal.com/expand-ii/)

**Some Considerations**

1. Yeast Health: Your yeast will be exposed to a higher osmotic pressure because of the higher sugar load. This is stressful to them if you haven't properly pitched the right number of yeast. Consider asking three people to empty a buffet designed to feed fifty. Pitching rates are based on degrees Plato, so a higher gravity wort will require more yeast, of a strain that can handle the higher load.
2. Colour: Colour, despite what one might think, does not change linearly with dilution, so your colour may not be what you expect when you dilute.
3. Bitterness: When you calculated your initial post-boil volume, your bitterness was also based on this volume. If you dilute, you will lower your IBU proportionately.
4. ***Sanitation***: This should go without saying, but don't ruin your beer by diluting with straight tap water. Boil the water first, cool it down quickly, make sure you're doing things in a sanitary manner.
5. Ion content and Water profile: When diluting high gravity worts / beers, you'll want to make sure your water profile is similar to that of the beer. This is less of a concern on the homebrew scale, but all the same, if you filtered before filter now etc.